# Hide table with ng-hide on click?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my html:

```
 <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="modelRow.activeRow==car.name" class="hidden-table">
    <td colspan="6">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Reviews</th>
```

As you can see I have `ng-show="modelRow.activeRow==car.name"`. I also have nav-tabs and  when I click on another tab the table is still showing up. **So how can I hide my table with `ng-click` on some button?**

Comment: Please provide a plnkr or jsfiddle.

Comment: Can you please provide: 1. `ng-repeat-start` tag 2. Ideally - create some plunk or jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on button click set some flag say hide_table to 1 . And then in table tag check for hide_table tag value using `ng-show`